# Looking for a Java keyboard-based map making program I lost

Tags: tools, product-identification, map-making

I used to have a Java-based mapper, but I lost it somewhere migrating between Win8 and Linux. As far as I remember it had the following specifications:

- Coded in Java - not Javascript.
- Not web/browser based.
- 2D/grid-based.
- It was unique in that the coder used WASD for map movement and other key combos for specific input functions. This (in his view) freed up the mouse/arrow keys for game functions.
- Not much in the way of tiles - just basic stuff... walls, doors, etc. By his own admission it was a work in progress.

I don't think he officially chose a name for it, and I remember that he stated on his page, he had eventually released it into the public domain.

Now, I have a problem: I can recall neither his name nor the URL. Any help to identify this tool is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this since it wasn't a shopping/recommendation request; it's a product identification.

Comment: Found it. I figured I'd keep searching in case I got lucky. I found a link on an rpgcodex post. [ http://www.zerker.ca/zzone/2010/01/10/dungeon-mapper-0-1-alpha/ ] Someone picked it up & put it on Github (link in one of the page's responses), but it appears to have stalled there for @4 years. Thanks.

Comment: @jafo123 That's great news. Should the question happen to be reopened and should you wish, you could self-answer it with that program and collect some points.

Comment: @jafo213 The question has been reopened—if you're still around, please feel free to turn that into an answer to help your fellow RPG players in the future ([answering your own question is OK here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer))! If not, I'm sure someone else will eventually.

Answer (score 12):

This was [*Dungeon Mapper*](http://www.zerker.ca/zzone/2010/01/10/dungeon-mapper-0-1-alpha/) by *Zerker* of *Zerk Zone* ([source code also available on GitHub](https://github.com/majutsushi/dungeonmapper)). This was originally pointed out by the questioner but they haven't written an answer yet.